# Alfred Terminal / Shell Command does not work

Tags: macos, applescript, iterm, alfred

In Alfred, if I type `> ls` must open iTerm2 with that command. Well, does not work for me.

In Application if I select Terminal instead of iTerm2, works.

[image]

If I select Application → Custom, it shows the applescript code you can see below and works.

[image]

If I select Application → Custom and modify the `tell application` line replacing Terminal with iTerm, does not work.

[image]

If I open Script Editor and type the following applescript code, does not work:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    do script "ls"
end tell
```

If I remove `do script` line open iTerm.

Any ideas of why `do script` line does not work with iTerm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way, but, from now, this is the only way that works for me:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    set the clipboard to q
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events" to tell (name of application processes whose frontmost is true) to keystroke "v" using command down
    tell application "System Events" to tell (name of application processes whose frontmost is true) to keystroke return
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example that I derived from the example in https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/AppleScript

Check out the comment from stefan.v...@gmail.com

```
tell application "iTerm"
    activate

    try
        set _session to current session of current terminal
    on error
        set _term to (make new terminal)
        tell _term
            launch session "Default"
            set _session to current session
        end tell
    end try

    tell _session
        write text "ls"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: With `exec command q` I get a Syntax Error: Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier.

Comment: Please paste the entire script please.

Comment: Replace `do script` line with `exec command "ls"` from my question.

Comment: Syntax Error: Expected end of line but found identifier. on line `set _session to current session of current terminal`, the error appears on the word `terminal`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Alfred blog post](https://www.alfredapp.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/better-iterm-integration-in-alfred/): "You can find some excellent iTerm integration AppleScripts for the older and newer versions of iTerm on Alfred user Stuart C Ryan's Custom iTerm Applescripts for Alfred Github page."

Script for iTerm 2.1.1:

```
-- This is v0.3 of the custom script for AlfredApp for iTerm 2.1.1
-- Please see https://github.com/stuartcryan/custom-iterm-applescripts-for-alfred/
-- for the latest changes.

on is_running(app_name)
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains app_name
end is_running

-- Please note, if you store the iTerm binary in any other location than the Applications Folder
-- please ensure you update the two locations below (in the format of : rather than / for folder dividers)
-- this gets around issues with AppleScript not handling things well if you have two iTerm binaries on your system... which can happen :D

on alfred_script(q)
    if is_running("iTerm") then
        run script "
            on run {q}
                tell application \":Applications:iTerm.app\"
                    activate
                    try
                        set myterm to the first terminal
                    on error
                        set myterm to (make new terminal)
                    end try
                    tell myterm
                        set mysession to (launch session \"Default Session\")
                        tell mysession to write text q
                    end tell
                end tell
            end run
        " with parameters {q}
    else
        run script "
            on run {q}
                tell application \":Applications:iTerm.app\"
                    activate
                    tell the first terminal
                        tell the last session to write text q
                    end tell
                end tell
            end run
        " with parameters {q}
    end if
end alfred_script
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Alfred v3.7 and iTerm2 v3.2.0 and MacOS v10.13.6, this solution works:

```applescript
on alfred_script(q)

    tell application "iTerm"
        activate

        set _profile to "Default"

        -- if there are no terminal windows...
        if (current window is missing value) then
            set _window to (create window with profile _profile)

        -- otherwise get the current window and open a new tab
        else
            set _window to current window
            tell _window
                create tab with profile _profile
            end tell
        end if

        -- execute the command
        tell current session of _window
            write text q
        end tell

    end tell

end alfred_script
```